# Undeclared indentifier compile error

Tags: c++, include, identifier

I am throwing myself in the cold blizzard of learning C++. I already know Java but C++ seems odd on certain thing.

Here is the thing : I have a class A and a class B. Class A have an instance of class B inside of itself. Class B needs to be able to call some class A methods so, I put a pointer to class A inside class B's constructor, and store it inside a variable so I can retrieve these methods with this variable.

Here is my code (simplified) :

#### ClassA.h

```
#ifndef CLASSA
#define CLASSA

#include "ParentClass.h"
#include "ClassB.h"

class ClassA : public ParentClass {

private:
ClassB *classB;

public:
ClassA(void);
virtual ~ClassA(void);

};
#endif
```

#### ClassA.cpp

```
   #include "ClassA.h"

   //-----------------------------------------------------
   ClassA::ClassA(void){
    classB= new ClassB(this);
   }
   //-----------------------------------------------------
   ClassA::~ClassA(void)
   {
   }
   //-----------------------------------------------------
```

#### ClassB.h

```
#ifndef CLASSB
#define CLASSB

#include "ClassA.h"

class ClassB{

public:
ClassB(ClassA &pClassA){ classA = pClassA; };
ClassA *getClassAInstance(){ return classA; };

private:
ClassA *classA;
};
#endif
```

#### ClassB.cpp

```
#include "ClassA.h"

/*ClassB::ClassB(void){
classA= pClassA;
}*/
```

Visual Express doesn't give errors but when I compile, it says that class B doesn't recognize what is a class A. What the hell ?

> 1>c:\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\ClassB.h(8): error C2061: syntax
>   error : identifier 'ClassA'
>
> 1>c:\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\ClassB.h(10): error C2143: syntax
>   error : missing ';' before '*'
>
> 1>c:\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\ClassB.h(10): error C4430:
>   missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support
>   default-int
>
> 1>c:\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\ClassB.h(10): error C4430:
>   missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support
>   default-int
>
> 1>c:\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\ClassB.h(10): warning C4183:
>   'getClassAInstance': missing return type; assumed to be a member
>   function returning 'int'
>
> 1>c:\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\ClassB.h(13): error C2143: syntax
>   error : missing ';' before '*'
>
> 1>c:\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\ClassB.h(13): error C4430:
>   missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support
>   default-int
>
> 1>c:\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\ClassB.h(13): error C4430:
>   missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support
>   default-int
>
> 1>c:\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\ClassB.h(8): error C2065:
>   'classA' : undeclared identifier
>
> 1>c:\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\ClassB.h(8): error C2065:
>   'pClassA' : undeclared identifier
>
> 1>c:\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\ClassB.h(10): error C2065:
>   'classA' : undeclared identifier

Undeclared what ? Returning int ?

> undeclared identifier

Why? I included everything, right ? Any ideas what is wrong, guys ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because of a circular reference between your header files. You can break it by forward-declaring one of the classes inside the header of the other, like this:

```
#ifndef CLASSA
#define CLASSA

#include "ParentClass.h"
//#include "ClassB.h" <<<<< Circular reference is now broken

class ClassB; // Added a forward declaration for use below.

class ClassA : public ParentClass {

private:
ClassB *classB;

public:
ClassA(void);
virtual ~ClassA(void);

};
#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

Including `class A`'s header in `class B` and `class B`'s header in `class A` is forming a cyclic dependency. That's why you are getting the compiler error. Instead try to use `Forward Declaration` in one of the header files.

#### ClassB.h

```
#ifndef CLASSB
#define CLASSB

class ClassA; //forward declaration of ClassA

class ClassB{

public:
ClassB(ClassA* pClassA){ classA = pClassA; };
ClassA *getClassAInstance(){ return classA; };

private:
ClassA *classA;
};
#endif
```

And include the header file of `ClassA` in `ClassB.cpp` to access the implementation of `ClassA` members.

Answer (score 1):

You made a cyclic dependency in header files, and they are included in that order:

1. ClassA.h
2. ClassB.h

`ClassB` is not declared when is used in `ClassA`, because header ClassB.h will be not included a second time (`CLASS_B` was already defined earlier).

Add

```
class ClassB;
```

before the `ClassA` definition.

Comment: Great guys, thank you all ! But now it tells me :

> 1>c:\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\ClassA.cpp(6): error C2514: 'ClassB' : class has no constructors
> 1>          c:\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\ClassA.h(10) : see declaration of 'ClassB'

Even if I declared a constructor with every fine in it !

Comment: @turbodoom which class did you forward declare? if you forward declared ClassB in `ClassA.h`, make sure you also include the header of ClassB in `ClassA.cpp`

Comment: @Meysam I forward declared in ClassA.h as well, now it works. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid this, use [forward declaration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_declaration) in Header files whenever it's possible. This can also reduce compile time a lot.